# Why not use 'protected' or 'private' in PHP?

Tags: php, encapsulation

I've been working with the Joomla framework and I have noticed that they use a convention to designate private or protected methods (they put an underscore "`_`" in front of the method name), but they do not explicitly declare any methods `public`, `private`, or `protected`.  Why is this?  Does it have to do with portability?  Are the `public`, `private`, or `protected` keywords not available in older versions of PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

public, private and protected are PHP5 keywords. unfortunately, PHP4 still has a very high install base (especially amongst shared hosting services).

here's a [pretty pic](http://www.nexen.net/images/stories/phpversion/200807/evolution.milieu.png) showing july usage rates (text in french). **spoiler**: php4 still has over a 35% usage rate sadly.

Comment: PHP4 will generate an E_STRICT warning.

Comment: E_STRICT was introduced in PHP5, unless i'm misunderstanding what you're saying

Comment: The opposite was true for a while: the first few PHP 5 releases complained when "var" was used.

Comment: The graph you have linked ends in 2008. On the other hand 4.3 and 4.4 are mentioned separately. Anyway, when you look at a more actual statistic, its quite different: http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all Only 10% PHP4

Answer (score 3):

There's some good arguments for not using `private` methods and properties over here: http://aperiplus.sourceforge.net/visibility.php

Includes: makes coding and reading code harder. Makes re-using classes and debugging harder.

I'm not sold either way, but I would like to see an informed rebuttal of that article, if one exists.

Comment: +1 for a very interesting (and persuasive) link. So, in the last two years, which way did you choose?

Comment: Heh, in the last two years, I haven't done much PHP coding :P. but I'm generally in favour of giving people enough rope :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP5 introduced some hefty changes in the object model.  Among supporting visibility, there are various other changes.  Be sure to check out:

[PHP 4 classes and objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop.php)

[PHP 5 classes and objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)